# CMake linked a compiled static library with a shared library

Tags: c, cmake, android-ndk

I am using dart:ffi to interoperate with some C code in order to use the SDK provided by [ZeroTier](https://docs.zerotier.com/sockets/tutorial.html). I have tried and successfully call out a dummy function from the shared library produced by CMake. This is the CMakeList.txt.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)  

add_library( 
            weather
            SHARED
            ../../src/weather.c
)
```

I have followed the documentation of [ZeroTierSDK](https://github.com/zerotier/libzt#zerotier-sdk) and the output of the compilation is the .dll and .a files. May I know what is the proper way to link the shared library produced from my .c file with the compiled library (.a / .dll) so that I could use the functions provided by the sdk?
I have tried adding the following lines to the CMakeList.txt.

```
link_directories ("../../src/libzt.lib")
target_link_libraries(weather ../../src/libzt.lib)
```

The error that I get was as below, I have confirmed that the lib was located in the same director as my .c file.

```
 C:/Users/DELL/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.1.6352462/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: error: cannot find -l../../src/libzt.lib
```

Comment: Two items: a .lib file is typically used on windows, not on Android (there you expect to see `.a` or `.so` files). Second, relative path names are relative to the *build* directory, not the *source* directory. Use `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}` and/or `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}` to make it absolute.

Comment: I think you are best off running the Android build instructions `./build.sh android-aar` and then grabbing the built `.so` files from the build tree into your `jniLibs`. Or just incorporate the zt CMakeLists.txt and link to the targets directly.

Comment: The `.so` files unable to compile, seems like the build script got several bugs. I have gave up this method. Thanks for your help.